# Firebase Functions: How to set a function region using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Node.js for my Firebase Functions. Please look at my func below. I want to set this func to be located in `europe-west1`.

This works:

```
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
exports.myFunc = onDocumentCreated("/stories/{documentId}", (event) => {…});
```

This doesn't work:

```
const {functions} = require("firebase-functions");
exports.myFunc = functions.region("europe-west1").onDocumentCreated("/stories/{documentId}", (event) => {…});
```

Deploy error:

> 'onDocumentCreated' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: You have a misunderstanding about TypeScript and node. TypeScript is a programming language which is a superset of JavaScript.  It get compiled down to JavaScript before it's run.  node is a JavaScript runtime, not a programming language - it just executes JavaScript in a process.  There is such thing as "TypeScript instead of node", since node just executes the JavaScript that was derived from TypeScript, if that's what you've chosen to use (there is no obligation to use TS - you opt into it for your project).

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, I see, but it's pretty weird for me as an Android developer to operate with different-looked code which the same in functional. So what about region for my func? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to be more clear what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried that doesn't work the way you expect (your [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including logs and error messages), and remove the final question which doesn't have anything to do with problem at hand.

Comment: @DougStevenson here you are, pls take a look to my edits

Comment: The example you show that works has nothing to do with TypeScript.  It is just plain JavaScript that also works if you have opted into TypeScript.  Why can't you use that?  It is exactly what's shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen). It seems you are also mixing up the difference between v1 and v2 functions supported by Firebase.  They have different APIs. You have imported v2, so you should use v2 syntax.

Comment: The example that works has no region option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentcreated_2) for Firebase Functions v2, you pass it in as the first argument (inside the [`DocumentOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.documentoptions.md#firestoredocumentoptions_interface) object, which extends the [`GlobalOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface) object):

```
const onDocumentCreated(
  {
    region: 'europe-west1',
    document: '/stories/{documentId}'
  }, 
  (event) => {

  }
);
```

Comment: You save my day, thanks! By the way this example doen't documented in Firebase at all.

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko It is documented, as I did link the official API reference - which should be treated as the primary documentation for the Firebase SDKs. The "Build Guides" are walkthroughs to support the API reference. Unfortunately they are not updated as often, and as thoroughly, as they should be. Every build guide has "Was this helpful?"/"Send Feedback" actions in the top right corner of the page. I encourage you to submit your feedback to the team to get this added.